# E73: tag stack empty while creating a map<leader>

Tags: key-bindings, leader

When I append `map <leader>tn  :tabnew<CR>` to my .vimrc and while tried to run this with `:,tn` command it says `E73: tag stack empty`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

1. (Most) maps of this form that I have seen want to be run in normal mode. So you need to press your leader key followed by <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>, without any colons.
2. Dont use regular `map`. It does too much, and is too easy to break. Prefer in this case a `noremap` variant `nnoremap` (for normal mode mappings).

Your command fails because vim runs the command `tagnext` (abbreviation: `tn`) with an empty range, and the tagstack is empty. You probably meant to have `,tn` make a new tab, with `,` as your leader:

```
" make leader whatever you want
nnoremap <Leader>tn :tabnew<CR>
```